# textArea growByContent doesnt work in layer layout

Tags: codenameone

I used layer layout to keep the title ie textArea on top of button image. But i cannot grow textArea size. Also the padding and margin on the textArea is not working as well.

```
            Image btnIcon = URLImage.createToStorage(placeholder, "homeIcon" + imageUrl, allUrl.globalHomeImageUrl + imageUrl, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);
            int width = placeholder.getWidth();
            int height = placeholder.getHeight();
            homeButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
            homeButton.getAllStyles().setBgImage(btnIcon);

            TextArea buttonTitle = new TextArea(title);
            buttonTitle.setRows(1);
            buttonTitle.setUIID("smallLabel");
            buttonTitle.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            buttonTitle.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 4, 0, 4);
            buttonTitle.setPreferredW(screenWidth / 3 - 30);
            buttonTitle.setEditable(false);
            buttonTitle.setGrowByContent(true);
            buttonTitle.setIsScrollVisible(false);
            buttonTitle.setGrowLimit(2);
            Container container1 = new Container();
            container1.setUIID("buttonTitleContainer");
            container1.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 5, 0, 0);
            container1.getAllStyles().setBgTransparency(0);
            container1.add(LayeredLayout.encloseIn(homeButton,     FlowLayout.encloseRightBottom(buttonTitle)));
            middleContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, container1);
```

How can i grow the textArea row as required and set the padding margin of the textarea.

Update: 
   i commented setPreferredW() and added calcPreferredSize() to set the dimension but how can i set the height dynamically??

```
TextArea buttonTitle = new TextArea(title){

                        @Override
                        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
                            Dimension d = new Dimension(screenWidth/3-10, 40);
                            return d; //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
                        }

                    };
                    buttonTitle.setUIID("smallLabel");
                    buttonTitle.getAllStyles().setAlignment(Label.LEFT);
                    buttonTitle.setRows(1);
                    buttonTitle.getAllStyles().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    buttonTitle.getAllStyles().setMargin(0, 0, 0, 4);
//                    buttonTitle.setPreferredW(screenWidth / 3 - 30);
                    buttonTitle.setEditable(false);
                    buttonTitle.setGrowByContent(true);
                    buttonTitle.setIsScrollVisible(false);
                    buttonTitle.setGrowLimit(2);
                    buttonTitle.setScrollVisible(false);
```

the design is somewhat like below:

[image]

Current screenshot: 
As you can see, there is only one word displayed and the textArea always has only 1 row and doesnt grow

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the `LayeredLayout` it's due to the fact that you called the deprecated `setPreferredW`.

Notice that `setPreferredW` also limits the height.

Comment: thanks i remove the setPreferredW and use calcPreferredSize but i cannot  make it all right. I have updated the question above. Plz have a look. Thankyou

Comment: I don't understand the goal of `container1`? Its a `FlowLayout` container that seems to wrap things?

Comment: container1 is set to gridlayout that adds components of a no. of layerlayouts to place textArea on bottom right corner of button. I have uploaded the design i want to achieve above. Have a look at it.

Comment: You removed the image of what you have right now so it isn't really helpful as I have no idea what you are doing wrong. If you are using a grid layout without wrapping stuff in the flow layout then you don't need the preferred size as the grid layout will take over the full cell size just like in the design. You can determine rows/columns as you would like them to be: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/layouts/package-summary.html

Comment: Actually i use setBgImage in the button, so the btn doesnt display bg image unless i set the size. sory the previous img got deleted by accident i updated the current img again.

Comment: Overriding `calcPreferredSize` is no different to setting the preferred size. You are effectively disabling the scale behavior of the text area which is implemented exactly there. If you want to limit the text are to the bottom right portion of the screen use something like `FlowLayout.encloseBottomRight`, use a TableLayout with the right cell constraint or use the SOUTH position of the border layout + margin to leave space on the left side.

Comment: but i need textArea on top of button Image, so i used layered layout. I think i cannot do that in borderlayout or tablelayout, can i?

Comment: Nest the `TextArea` in a `Container` that has that layout and put that `Container` in the `LayeredLayout`. See the section in the developer guide that does exactly that!

Comment: yeah i exactly did that according to the developers guide but my main issue here is that the textArea has only one row no matter what. I set the textArea setGrowByContent true and setGrowLimit to 2 but it is not working. If i dont use preferredW, the textArea grows out of the button. I dont know what to do. So i twisted the code and set height of the textArea by twice its height if textArea width is greater than button width but some problem exist there too.
[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35967581/re-textarea-growbylimit-issues-in-layerlayout)

Comment: Use nesting. LayeredLayout should normally contain other containers and not the TextArea directly.

Comment: Doesn't ' FlowLayout.encloseRightBottom(buttonTitle) ' makes buttonTitle which is a textArea nest itself in a container? I check component inspector and there is a container with flowLayout that contains textArea. However i kept textArea in a separate container too but same result

Comment: It does but you still override the calc preferred size so that won't change anything.